# Docx to Google Doc using Google Script

Tags: google-apps, google-docs-api

I have a lot of docx files ( ~ 72 ) , their MIMETYPE is :

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

and I want to convert all of them to GoogleDocument so I can edit them online to do so I need them to be

```
application/vnd.google-apps.document
```

Is this possible ? I've tried with blob but nothing works , there is a way to create a new google doc with the same format ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it .

```
var docx = DriveApp.getFileById("###");
var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
var blob =docx.getBlob();
var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
```

The `{convert:true}` convert it .
Ps : you need to set document name since it's not included in teh blob

```
DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());
```