# How to convert .docx files to Google Docs with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Does anyone has experience in convert a batch of .docx file, stored in Google Drive, to Google Docs format?

I read [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615415/docx-to-google-doc-using-google-script/59535010#59535010) posted 3 years ago by Youssef, but it is not working anymore.

When I try to replicate the solution, I get this error message:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

```
var docx = DriveApp.getFileById("###");

var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
var blob =docx.getBlob();
var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
```

Execution stops at `docx.getBlob()`.

Answer (score 6):

This function uses some of the advanced Drive APIs and as such, require you to enable them from the script editor first, **before** running the script. To achieve this, go to:

**Resources > Advanced Google Services... >** Scroll all the way down to **Drive API** > toggle the *off* button to *on*

[image: Advanced resources]

Here's the final script -

```
function myFunction() {
  var docx = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Dummy.docx').next();
  var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
  var blob =docx.getBlob();
  var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
  DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());  
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sourabh! Thanks for your feedback! I run your code, but it still stops on the line that call getBlob() method. I also enabled the advanced service for Drive API. Could it work correctly in your side?

Comment: Sourabh, I reviewed my code and it working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, missed your earlier comment but glad I could help!