# Unable to access .docx file in Google Docs Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing a Google Docs Add-on using Appsscript which reads the body of the Google Docs and displays it in the add-on UI.

To access the Google doc I am using the the following code:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody().getText();
```

The code was working file for Google Docs files.

Then, I tried reading the text or body of .docx file and I got the following exception:

> Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later.
> [Exception Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlS0.png)

I looked into the various solutions given on StackOverflow but couldn't get the resolution. The answers on StackOverflow says to convert the .docx file into doc file. However, I couldn't do so as I am unable to get the "ID" of opened document.

I will be grateful if anyone suggests me how to get the ID of the opened document or how to get the ID of document from the browser URL or how to resolve this exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading Microsoft Doc will not be possible, you need to convert it into Google Docs first.

Comment: For getting ID, use this `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()`

Comment: Hold on... It looks like opened .docx files have no script feature at all https://imgur.com/Fpmk0ap.png How did exactly you try to run your code and where you get the Exception message?

Comment: Yes, I need to convert it into the Google Docs first but I am not able to get the ID of the document. I am getting the error at `getActiveDocument()` method. @DarpanSanghavi @Yuri

Comment: @YuriKhristich I need the code that you posted. Can you please provide me the same code here or on my email ? nowman.work@gmail.com

Comment: I just restored my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a URL, probably you can get an ID this way:

```js
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BxECZrrIQpKFJYN5zHUeUDxeEiB8NjEb/edit'

var id = url.split('/')[5]

console.log(id) // output: 1BxECZrrIQpKFJYN5zHUeUDxeEiB8NjEb
```

Then you can get the file by ID with `DriveApp` and convert it into Google doc. The fresh example how it can be done is here:

[Converting MS Word files (saved in Drive) to Google Docs using app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977186/converting-ms-word-files-saved-in-drive-to-google-docs-using-app-script)

If you have the URL of a .docx file (it's not clear to me from your question) the code could be something like this:

```
function main() {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/abcd123456789/edit';
  var id = url.split('/')[5];
  var doc_file = convert_docx_to_google_doc(id);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_file.id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText(); // <--- contents of the doc file is here

  console.log(text);

  DriveApp.getFileById(doc_file.id).setTrashed(true); // delete the doc file
}


// you need to enable Advanced Drive API Service

function convert_docx_to_google_doc(id) {
  var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var folder = docx.getParents().next();
  
  var google_doc = Drive.Files
    .insert(Drive.newFile(), docx.getBlob(), {convert:true});
  
  // it saves the file next to the original one in the same folder
  // it's not necessary if you don't need the file
  DriveApp.getFileById(google_doc.id)
    .setName(docx.getName().replace(/\.docx$/,'')).moveTo(folder);

  return google_doc; // return the google doc file
}
```

Comment: I do not have the URL and I could not find any way to get the URL from Docs Add-on. It will be helpful if you can suggest me a way to get the URL or the ID for .docx file. @Yuri

Comment: Did you have the .docx as an opened document in your browser in Google Doc App? How did you open it?

Comment: .docx file is opened in "Google Docs App". It is shared file, someone has shared it with me. I am developing workspace add-on extending Google Docs. @Yuri

Comment: For reference. I have added an image in the main question above. Please check it. @Yuri

Comment: How exactly the process of opening of the docx look like? Please, describe the steps.

Comment: Hi @Yuri,
Step1: go to [https://docs.google.com]
Step2: Select the .docx file and open it.

Comment: And how you run the script?

Comment: By opening the add-on. when i open my add-on, the method docs.homepageTriggerrunFunction is triggered. The code from manifest looks like the following:

`"docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDocsHomepage"
      }
}`

then inside onDocsHomepage() method i run the code to get the document details. 

The code you provided above is working fine for me if I hardcode the ID of the .docx document. Now i am stuck at getting the URL of the browser or getting the ID of the .docx document. The problem will be resolved if I get the ID of the .docx file.

@Yuri

Comment: Probably it's need a Google Drive add-on. Not Google Doc add-on. Unfortunately I'm not exactly an expert in add-ons. It looks like docx is not a proper document for Google Doc even if GDoc can show it and change via the web interface. It's still  just a file, a blob. Basically Google Drive App is meant to handle with any file (get a file ID, etc). Good luck

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts @Yuri, The code you provided worked for me if I have a browser URL.

Comment: I think it will be better if I delete my answer (at least temporary). It will increase the chances that someone else try to answer it. Usually if there is an answer already (even not accepted one) nobody tries to look at the question :( . This is why it's important to mark correct answers as accepted -- to separate unanswered questions (even if there are some incomplete of wrong answers, like we have here) from actually answered.