# How to convert .docx files to Google Docs with Apps Script? (2024 - Drive API V3)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried following the instructions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535096/how-to-convert-docx-files-to-google-docs-with-apps-script), specifically this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535930/22813224).

I was getting an error

> TypeError: Drive.Files.insert is not a function

Since "insert" doesn't exist in the documentation of the Drive API v3 (only v2), I tried using "Drive.Files.create" instead, but them got the error

> Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later

This is the part of the code I was using from that post/answer:

```
var docx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nomeArquivo).next();
var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
var blob =docx.getBlob();
var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});

DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());
```

The error

> TypeError: Drive.Files.insert is not a function

occurred on this line:

```
var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
```

I've tried to fix the error, using "create" instead of "insert":

```
var file = Drive.Files.create(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
```

But now I'm getting an error

> Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later

on this line:

```
DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());
```

Any suggestions?

Here's the full code:

```
function AtualizarLinkDocs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pagListaArquivos = ss.getSheetByName("Lista de Arquivos");
  var rangeLinks = pagListaArquivos.getRange('K1:M').getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i<rangeLinks.length; i++){
    if (rangeLinks[i][0]!="" && rangeLinks[i][2]==""){
    var caminhoNomeArquivo = rangeLinks[i][0];
    var nomeArquivo = caminhoNomeArquivo.toString().replace("Lista de Arquivos_Files_/","");  
    var idWord = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nomeArquivo).next().getId();
    Logger.log(idWord);  


    var docx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nomeArquivo).next();
    var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
    var blob = docx.getBlob();
    var file = Drive.Files.create(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});

    DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());

    Logger.log("novo arquivo: "+file.id);

    }
  }
}
```

Where I'm going with this: I've got an appsheet app that I use to upload files to google drive, and it logs the name of the file in the spreadsheet. I'd like to take the files, which are always word documents, and create copies of them as google docs documents. Them I'll store the share link of the google docs on the spreadsheet, in a different column (I don't have this part on the code yet because I'm stuck trying to convert the word to google docs).

**UPDATE:**

I figured another problem with this line of code `var file = Drive.Files.create(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});` is that "convert:true" also doesn't exists in V3 documentation.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977186/converting-ms-word-files-saved-in-drive-to-google-docs-using-app-script) instead, and its working fine but for 1 key component: it was also V2 and it uses "{convert:true}" too. Now, I'm getting a copy of the word document, but its still a word document. This is the updated code:

```
function AtualizarLinkDocs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pagListaArquivos = ss.getSheetByName("Lista de Arquivos");
  var rangeLinks = pagListaArquivos.getRange('K1:M').getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i<rangeLinks.length; i++){
    if (rangeLinks[i][0]!="" && rangeLinks[i][2]==""){
    var caminhoNomeArquivo = rangeLinks[i][0];
    var nomeArquivo = caminhoNomeArquivo.toString().replace("Lista de Arquivos_Files_/","");  
    var idWord = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nomeArquivo).next().getId();
    Logger.log("Id do Word: "+idWord);  

  var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(idWord);
  var folder = docx.getParents().next();
  var blob = docx.getBlob();
  Logger.log(blob);
  var new_file = Drive.newFile();
  var google_doc = Drive.Files.create(new_file.id,blob);
  Logger.log(google_doc);

  DriveApp.getFileById(google_doc.id)
    .setName(docx.getName()
    .replace(/\.docx$/,''))
    .moveTo(folder);

  Logger.log("será que foi?? Docs: "+google_doc.id)

    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to modify the blob and the file a number of times using
`.getAs('application/vnd.google-apps.document')`, but its not working, it absolutely always results in the following error:

> Exception: Converting from application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document to application/vnd.google-apps.document is not supported.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Have you checked answer provided below?

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement required functionality of getting Google Docs file from .docx file, using Google Apps Script, the following code can be checked.

```
var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(idWord);
var folder = docx.getParents().next();
var blob = docx.getBlob();
let file_options = {
    name: docx.getName()
.replace(/\.docx$/,''),
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS
};
var google_doc = Drive.Files.create(file_options, blob);
DriveApp.getFileById(google_doc.id)
.moveTo(folder);
```

It can be checked, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, Drive API v3 is selected as the default version. About the difference between v2 and v3 can be seen at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/v2-to-v3-reference). And, this thread might be also useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77675659)
- In the case that a Microsoft Docs file is converted to a Google Docs file, "Method: files.copy" of Drive API v3 can be also used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/copy) In this case, the blob is not required to be used. The conversion can be done only with the file ID. And, if there are many files, the batch requests can be also used to reduce the process cost.
- In your showing script, at `var rangeLinks = pagListaArquivos.getRange('K1:M').getValues();`, all rows are retrieved. In this case, retrieving only the data range might be suitable.
- If the file of the filename does not exist, an error occurs.
- If the mimeType of the file is the mimeType that it cannot be converted to Google Document, an error occurs.

When these points are reflected in your top script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function AtualizarLinkDocs() {
  // Retrieve the mimeTypes that can be converted to Google Document.
  var mimeTypes = Object.entries(Drive.About.get({ fields: "importFormats" }).importFormats).filter(([_, v]) => v.find(e => e == MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)).map(([k]) => k);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pagListaArquivos = ss.getSheetByName("Lista de Arquivos");
  var rangeLinks = pagListaArquivos.getRange('K1:M' + pagListaArquivos.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < rangeLinks.length; i++) {
    if (rangeLinks[i][0] != "" && rangeLinks[i][2] == "") {
      var caminhoNomeArquivo = rangeLinks[i][0];
      var nomeArquivo = caminhoNomeArquivo.toString().replace("Lista de Arquivos_Files_/", "");
      var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nomeArquivo);
      if (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        if (mimeTypes.includes(file.getMimeType())) {
          var fileId = file.getId();
          var obj = Drive.Files.copy({ name: file.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [file.getParents().next().getId()] }, fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true });
          var documentId = obj.id;
          console.log(documentId);
          var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);

          // do something.

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the filenames are retrieved from column "K" of the sheet "Lista de Arquivos", and when the file of the filename exists and the mimeType of the file is the mimeType that can be converted to Google Document, the file is converted to Google Document. And, the converted Google Document is created in the same folder as the original file.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already enabled Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get)
- [Method: files.copy of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/copy)